# Javascript - how to work with the iterator in a for loop with callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

I am trying in the for loop to access the value of the i with which the callback function uses.

How can I do this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    calcRoute(fixedLocation, my_cities[i].address, function(response) {

        // i want here to have the current "i" here

    });             
}
```

which calls...

```
function calcRoute(x, y, callback) {

    var start = x;
    var end = y;

    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        optimizeWaypoints: true
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            callback(response);                                                                 
        } else {
            alert("City unknown.")
        }       
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because the closure captures the variable `i` itself, not the current value. Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) (function(i)
{
    calcRoute(fixedLocation, my_cities[i].address, function(response) {

        // i want here to have the current "i" here

    });             

}) (i);
```

which will create a new `i` variable for each loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most elegant way to do it is just using `Array.forEach`:

```
a.forEach(function(someA, i) {
    calcRoute(fixedLocation, my_cities[i].address, function(response) {

        // i want here to have the current "i" here

    });
});
```

The callback function gets passed:

1. the current element
2. the current index
3. the array it was called upon

Leaving out arguments just means you can’t access them in the callback. (Often you leave out the index and just use the current element).

---

If `a` is a `NodeList`, which doesn’t have `forEach`, just do:

```
Array.forEach.call(a, function(someA, i) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

  function createCallback(i) {
    return function(response) {
      // i want here to have the current "i" here
    }
  }

  calcRoute(fixedLocation, my_cities[i].address, createCallback(i));
}
```