# infowindow.setContent all the same thing...dealing with closures/Google Maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, closures, infowindow

I've been wrestling with this `infowindow.setContent(address);` for hours. Based on what I've read on here I know it has to do something with closures but I can't get it to work. Both of my info windows are the same right now.

Here's the test site right now, sorry for the poor appearance :)

http://testsite.edwardgranger.com/2013/12/05/hello-world/

PHP & js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var o = <?php echo json_encode($m_userArray); ?>
</script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker;
    var i;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    for(var i = 3; i <= 4; i++) {


        var address = window.o[i].address;

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
          } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I've tried a few different concepts but honestly I just found out about closures tonight and I understand them on a higher level but trying to navigate my code is a chore, a second set of eyes would be great right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google map info window multiple addresses via xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278368/google-map-info-window-multiple-addresses-via-xml)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - how to work with the iterator in a for loop with callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377971/javascript-how-to-work-with-the-iterator-in-a-for-loop-with-callbacks)

Comment: The problem is that inside addListener will be passed the same address. What you can do is 1)since you pass i, replace address with window.o[i].address or 2)instead of i, pass address as the parameter with marker. It is indeed a duplicate post. But I remember the hard time I had with this particular issue so I'm sentimental :P.

Comment: @alkis geocodezip ended up giving the best answer. I had been trying some of your methods and i think it may have been something else. I still need to understand this better to know exactly what went wrong.

Comment: @geocodezip i was able to solve my problem by working through your answer i will submit what I got moving.